# UIBezierPath support for relative paths?

Tags: ios, uibezierpath

I read the Apple documentation to the [UIBezierPath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath?language=objc) object. Do I understand this correctly that it doesn't support relative paths?

I'm trying to convert this svg path into an UIBezierPath:

```
// svg path
m90 36c-7 0-13 6-13 13s6 13 13 13 13-6 13-13-6-13-13-13zm-27 32c-7 0-13 6-13 13s6 13 13 13 13-6 13-13-6-13-13-13z
```

I started with:

```
UIBezierPath* myPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
CGPoint currentPoint;

[myPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake([self sizeDependendX:90], [self sizeDependendY:36])];
currentPoint = CGPathGetCurrentPoint(myPath.CGPath);
[myPath addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(currentPoint.x - 13, currentPoint.y + 13)
          controlPoint1:CGPointMake(currentPoint.x +  7, currentPoint.y +  0)
          controlPoint2:CGPointMake(currentPoint.x - 13, currentPoint.y +  6)];
currentPoint = CGPathGetCurrentPoint(myPath.CGPath);
[myPath addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(currentPoint.x + 13 ,currentPoint.y + 13)
          controlPoint1:CGPointMake(currentPoint.x +  0, currentPoint.y +  7)
          controlPoint2:CGPointMake(currentPoint.x +  6, currentPoint.y + 13)];
...
```

Is it really meant to be like that or do I miss something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, there are simply **no** "relative" points.

(If really needed, it's trivial to make an extension, function, or some other sugar to make it tidy. In Swift I usually have something like

```
go(across: 7.0, down: -2.5)
go(across: 4.0, down: -2.5)
go(across: 7.0, down: -2.5)
```

.. sort of thing.  It's only a couple lines of code for the function or extension you want.)

Sorry for the bad news!  :)

---

We do a lot of bezier related stuff, here is how some typical code looks for us. I use zillions of helper calls so that the code makes more sense.

I would say that one really has to build on Apple's primitives, when writing up code to create complicated bezier material.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation of the "bad news". Do you have some background information of **why** there are non relative points?

Comment: cheers @BrunoBieri , to be honest I don't have any take on that.  It would seem to me that the basic approach is simply the positions (ie, as they have it).  If they added "relative - to - the - previous - one - added" convenience functions, it would really just be an added extra you know?  As such, I guess it's just one of many things they "have not yet gotten around to!"

Comment: howdy @BrunoBieri - just to be clear, you're familar with the family of calls: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624354-addline also addCurve#to etc etc ?

Comment: @BrunoBieri one more thing, I added a real-life example of some idiomatic material, cheers

Comment: Thanks for the updates. It seems we've to do the same with helper methods.